# Use a push button to add a section in an InfoPath form?

Tags: windows, sharepoint, infopath, infopath-forms-services

I'm working on an InfoPath form that's going to be run with InfoPath Forms Services on a SharePoint server. For a number of reasons -- mostly so that the customer can update the form without involving an administrator -- this can't be a form containing .NET code.

The form has a repeating group, and we have users who are a bit confused as to how to add and delete items from the repeating section. I've looked all over the Internets, but haven't been able to find a way to do this without adding a code project to the form.

Is there any way to write a rule or do something else to make a button that adds an item to a repeating section?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using JavaScript instead? to add the functionality that you need.  Most (if not all) the samples within InfoPath contain a JavaScript code-behind files.  these should work within infopath forms services though I have not tried.